# get postback trigger

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to get the button id that triggered postback in Page_Load void?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string postbackControlName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
```

That should give you the name of the control that causes the postback.

Then use the Page.FindControl(postbackControlName); to get the control, which you can access the id of.

[See this article for more details.](http://haroonsaeed.wordpress.com/2006/10/09/how-to-check-which-control-has-caused-post-back/)